# Salesforce Certification or Salesforce real life projects?

Tags: developer, certification, project-structure

Which is more important Salesforce Certification or Salesforce real life projects? I already have 4 Certs (PD1, App Builder, Associate, AI Associate) and 1 year work experience. But I do NOT have any projects in my resume. Which should I be focusing on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, this is not the right place to ask this question.
Still, I suggest you focus on work experience rather than certifications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would always suggest for projects (project on trailhead are good to start with) and use certification specific trailmixes as guided path for upskilling yourself in new topics.

Comment: Thank you @Sumit. Good Day

Comment: @SainikBasu If you found this answer useful. can you please upvote?